Comparing Unsigned integers using AVX2 Intrinsics
I want to threshold values greater than 15 using AVX2 instructions but it compares only signed numbers.
    __m256i *pIn0, *pIn1,*pOut;
    __m256i a, b, thres = _mm256_set1_epi8(15); //Threshold value is set to 15
    
    for (int i = 0; i < nHeight; i++)
    {
        pIn0 = (__m256i*)(pY1 + i * nStepSize); //buffer 1 having 8 bit unsigned integers
        pIn1 = (__m256i*)(pY2 + i * nStepSize); //buffer 2 having 8 bit unsigned integers
        pOut = (__m256i*)(pdiffAnd + i * nStepSize);

        int wLimit = nWidth / 32;
        for (int j = 0; j < wLimit; j++)
        {
            a = _mm256_lddqu_si256(pIn0++); //32 values of UINT8 type
            b = _mm256_lddqu_si256(pIn1++); //32 values of UINT8 type


            __m256i diff1 = _mm256_or_si256(_mm256_subs_epu8(a, b), _mm256_subs_epu8(b, a)); //taking their absolute difference

      /* here _mm256_cmpgt_epi8 is comparing values assuming 8 bit Signed integers so values greater than 127 are not getting compared */
            __m256i diff1Mask = _mm256_cmpgt_epi8(diff1, thres);

            __m256i blend1 = _mm256_blendv_epi8(diff1, diff1Mask, diff1Mask);

            _mm256_store_si256(pOut++, blend1);
        }
    }

I thought a solution to find all values less than 0 and perform bitwise OR with diff1Mask but also got stuck to find values less than 0.
PS: I'm a newbie

See for example SSE Compare Packed Unsigned Bytes (those tricks can be converted to AVX2 the obvious way). BTW blend(a, mask, mask) can be simplified to a bitwise OR.

"I want to threshold values greater than 15 using AVX2": Do you want to use _mm256_min_epu8 maybe?

No @chtz I don't want to keep the threshold value, it's only for comparison

thanks @user555045 this will help me compressing values of UINT8 to SINT8 but I'm looking for comparing values less than 0

and can you please upvote @user555045

The linked question has answers showing how to do an unsigned comparison, ie an unsigned version of _mm256_cmpgt_epi8, isn't that what you wanted?

So you actually want something like result = (x > threshold ? 255 : x)?

Btw, please don't ask for upvotes: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403392/is-it-ok-to-leave-a-comment-asking-for-upvotes

Do you want the comparison to work even if the unsigned bit pattern corresponds to a negative number or is code that works only for positive thresholds <= 127 acceptable? What output do you want if input x<0 (0?) or x>15 (15 or 255) ?

Assuming your inputs are unsigned bytes

If you want 0xff for values at or above the threshold and 0 otherwise, the simplest is usually:
mask = _mm256_cmpeq_epi8(_mm256_min_epu8(x, threshold), threshold); -- 2uops
If you want something which can be used as mask input for a pblendvb instruction then:

If your threshold is 0x80 you can just use x (free)
If your threshold is below 0x80 you can add (0x80-threshold) with unsigned saturation (_mm256_adds_epu8) -- 1 uop.
If your threshold is above 0x80 you can subtract (threshold - 0x80) with unsigned saturation (_mm256_subs_epu8) -- 1uop.



If you want an expression equivalent to
result = x>=16 ? 255 : x;

this should be the simplest equivalent AVX2 expression:
const __m256i threshold = _mm256_set1_epi8(16);
result = _mm256_or_si256(_mm256_cmpeq_epi8(_mm256_min_epu8(x, threshold), threshold), x);

Using a pblendvb on most Intel architectures takes 2 uops (3 on Alder Lake-P) but you also need an additional 0xff constant -- if you already have that constant anyways, then this is about the same cost as the expression above (depends on the actual architecture and surrounding port usage) -- also on AMD ZEN2 or later this can be better (may also depend on context):
result = _mm256_blendv_epi8(x, _mm256_set1_epi8(255),
                            _mm256_adds_epu8(x, _mm256_set1_epi8(0x80 - 16)); 

